# Android NDK pthread_create shows “too many arguments, expected 1”

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, pthreads

Android Studio NDK project builds by CMake, when I use pthread_create method, the IDE show me the error "too many arguments, expected 1".

1.IDE code completion show "pthread_create(void* )", but it cannot pass compiling;

2.I search it in pthread.h

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t* _Nonnull, pthread_attr_t const*,
               void* (* _Nonnull start_routine)(void*), void*);
```

but it show red wave line tell me "too many arguments, expected 1".

3.BUT when I run it in my phone, it's no problem! Everything is correct except the red wave line.

I had read other relative questions but they cannot solved it. So, can somebody tell me why it happens and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ parser that Studio uses doesn't understand the `_Nonnull` keywords. The parser is wrong, your code is fine.